# comparing array's through index in Swift 2

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

For my education I build to build a dictionary app which is readable through picker view. It has basically a dutchwords array and a English words array.

And I can ad words as well. This is all working. And i though i could give the user the correct  throw their indexes.

```
//selected by picker view
if englishDic.index == dutchDic.index{ 
    //correct answer
}
else{
    //wrong answer
}
```

It doesn't work this way.

Comment: maybe post some more code?

Answer (score 1):

Arrays don't have an `index` property that you can access like that. What you probably want to do is capture the selected index for each picker in the Picker View's `didSelectRow` function in the [UIPickerViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/).

Once you've stored those in variables, you can compare the selected indexes.

Comment: It's important to note that the arrays are the 'data source' for the picker view. The array doesn't 'know' that it is being used by a picker view, so updating the selection in the picker view has no impact at all on the array.

Comment: @IBAction func checkTranslationButton(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        func pickerView(pickerview: UIPickerView, didSelectRow: Int, inComponent: Int)
        {
            var action1 = pickerView(<#T##pickerView: UIPickerView##UIPickerView#>, didSelectRow: 0, inComponent: 0)
            var action2 = pickerView(<#T##pickerView: UIPickerView##UIPickerView#>, didSelectRow: 0, inComponent: 1)
     
        
            
        }
The errors i get is that i can't get the int from the rows.

So I'm stuck. Sorry to bother you again.

Comment: The `didSelectRow` functions will get called when a user selects a row (as the name implies.) These shouldn't be nested in your 'button' function. You need to... 1 - create variables in your ViewController to store the selected index for each picker. 2 - Update these variables using the `didSelectRow` functions. 3 - Compare the variables in your `checkTranslationButton` function.

Comment: If you're going to get into iOS development, it's really important to be across the [Delegation Pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html). I can see that this is the concept you are struggling with here.

Comment: And that is my basic problem as well. how can i make the two variations to select the two rows/index from the picker view.